# Integrating ASP.NET MVC and jQueryMobile - DateBox

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-mobile, razor, datebox

jQueryMobile - DateBox needs this to work properly:

```
<label for="mydate">Some Date</label>

<input name="mydate" id="mydate" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "flipbox"}'>
```

But in Asp.Net MVC Razor Engine I have this for the Editor Label & Field:

```
<div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
    </div>
```

Is there a way to integrate the two things to have a jQueryMobile - DateBox in my Asp.Net MVC application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, nothing easier of HtmlAttributes.
So I risolved this question out.
The solution, if someone needs too:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ReleaseDate, new  { @name = "mydate", @id = "mydate", @type = "date", @data_role = "datebox", @data_options= " {'mode':'flipbox', 'dateFormat':'dd/mm/YYYY' } ")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
</div>
```

Only note the @ character before every attribute, the _ (underscore) character instead of the - (dash) one for the composite words attributes and the TextBoxFor instead of EditorFor.

Bye!